# DataPager PreRender messes with Chart controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, datapager, microsoft-chart-controls

I have a few problems when trying to use DataPager and Chart controls together.

I am currently working on a website for my final year project. However, I am stuck at a problem with the DataPager PreRender event, and the Chart controls being blanked out.

Here is my code:

```
    public void DataPager1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       getSource();
    }
```

getSource() calls the Chart Control codes, as well as displays tweets into a listview.

```
     protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                msg = new Message();
                msg.displayMessage("TEST");
                displayMessage("TEST");
                ListView1.DataSource = null;
                ListView1.DataBind();
                getSource();
         }
```

This calls the Chart controls the first time the user selects a Tweet Source.

However, when the page first loads, and a source is selected, the Pie Chart shows duplicate values. (e.g 2 Segments of the same name)

Another alternative I have tried was to call only the ListView portion from my getSource() function:

```
    public void DataPager1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
               {
                {
                 if (auth.CompleteAuthorization(Request.Url) == true)
                  {
                    var twitterCtx = new LinqToTwitter.TwitterContext(auth);

                    var tweets = from t in twitterCtx.Status
                                 where t.Type == StatusType.User && t.ScreenName == DropDownList1.SelectedValue
                                 select t;

                    ListView1.DataSource = tweets.ToArray();
                    ListView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

However, when I click on another page through the DataPaging, my Pie Charts go blank, as if there wasn't any data in the controls...

What am I doing wrong?

Do let me know if I am missing any important information...